# How can I set the value of a cell in Cells().Select command to the value of a cell that has a formula in it?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a macro that copies the values inside certain cells of sheet1 and pastes then in sheet2.

This is a formula that i wrote inside cell "AI2":

```
=IFERROR(SUM(1+AH:AH),"0")
```

and it produces a number that I want to use in the macro as a variable row coordinate.

This is the code i have in my worksheet in order to trigger the macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
     If Range("AI2") <> 0 Then
     Call macro1
     End If
End Sub
```

And this is the macro:

```
Sub macro1()
Dim RV As Integer
RV = Sheets("sheet1").Range("AI2").Value
Cells(RR, 33).Select
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6), ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("sheet2").Select
Range("A1048576").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

If I delete the first 3 lines of code, the macro works, but I have to manually select the cell for the offsets to reference from.

I need to make it so the value of cell "AI2" is used as the first coordinate in this line of code:

```
Cells(RR, 33).Select
```

I am very new to any kind of programming, but I want to learn this in order to achieve my goals for this spreadsheet and future ones with similar functions.

Comment: ([Please don't use `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)). Also, what is `Cells(RR, 33).Select`? Does that not throw an error? At the very least I'd think that needs to be `Cells(33,"RR")`?

Comment: Shouldn't `RR` be `RV`?

Comment: 'cells(RR, 33).select' RR would be the value of cell "AI2" which would match the row that has the info that needs copying, where the 33 would be the column (AG)

Comment: I corrected that but still, when I make the value of cell "AI2" change, even though it becomes unequal to "0", it does not trigger anything, but no error messages show

Comment: Worksheet_Change will not pickup a change due to a formula, only ones done manually.

Comment: To extend on @ScottCraner comment, you need to change your `Worksheet_Change` event to trigger when a manual change is made that you expect will make a change to `Range("AI2")`. So, it looks like you need your macro to look for changes in `Column AH` rather the entire sheet

Comment: If your value in AI2 = 5, what range will you be copying?

Comment: @urdearboy that would make the reference cell "AH5" and the range to copy "AB5:AG5"

Comment: I don't see why `AH5` is relevant here. If `AI2 = 5`, you want to copy `AB:AG` on 5th row? And if `AI2 = 10` you want to copy `AB:AG` on 10th row? If so, the solution I provided you will, *should*, work

Comment: @Nuno Filipe: You cannot upvote, yet. But soon when you'll have 15 reputation you can come back and do so. Thanks for the kind reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am limiting the scope of your `Worksheet_Change` to only fire when a change is registered in `Column AH` since this is the column that will trigger a formula change in `Column AI`

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 34 Then
        If Range("AI2") <> 0 Then
            Macro2
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim cs As Worksheet: Set cs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ps As Worksheet: Set ps = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim xRow As Long, LR As Long
LR = ps.Range("A" & ps.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
xRow = cs.Range("AI2").Value

cs.Range(cs.Cells(xRow, "AB"), cs.Cells(xRow, "AG")).Copy
    ps.Range("A" & LR).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: this worked to some extent, as it is always copying the top row within the (AB:AG) column range no matter the row within column 34. I will try to figure out how your code works as I don't know what half of those commands mean.

Thank you :)

Comment: @urdearboy I got it to work, the issue was that the `If Range("AI2") > 0...`  Needed to be `If Range("AI2") <> 0...` Because the way "AI2" formula is written
=IFERROR(SUM(1+AH:AH),"0")
the cell value was 1+whatever value would be in the AH column, so i'm guessing the macro was always looking for the 1. when i changed the ">" to "<>" it worked perfectly :)

Nonetheless I will still try to learn your code so i can eventually write working macros with my own knowledge

Thank you very much for the help :D

Comment: @VBasic2008 both of them worked and I thank you both, for the time and patience you expended with my post. I upvoted both solutions and accepted urdearboy's answer because his macro pasted the info in a new row every time it ran, making it so i keep all the info logged of  any row i edit in collumn "AH"

I hope that if we speak again, I will at least be able to understand the code

Again, Thank you very much for all the help and my apologies for the eventual dead neuron. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

## Copy Range to First Empty Cell

### Calculate

If you are using a formula in the cell range `AI2` you **should** use the **Worksheet Calculate** event which will occur everytime the formula is being calculated.

**Standard Module**

```
Option Explicit

Public Const strRange As String = "AI2"
Public vntValue As Variant

Sub macro1()

    Dim rng As Range  ' Target Cell Range
    Dim RV As Long    ' Row Value

    ' In Target Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        ' Calculate the first empty (unused) cell in column A (A1 not included).
        Set rng = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With

    ' In Source Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        ' Write the value of Row Cell to Row Value.
        RV = .Range(strRange).Value
        With .Cells(RV, "AH") ' or 33
            ' Copy range from "AB" to "AG" in row defined by Row Value in
            ' Source Worksheet to the range from "A" to "F" in row of Target
            ' Cell Range in Target Worksheet.
            rng.Resize(, 6) = Range(.Offset(0, -6), .Offset(0, -1)).Value
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

**Sheet1**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If vntValue <> Range(strRange).Value Then
        vntValue = Range(strRange).Value
        If Range(strRange).Value <> "0" Then macro1
    End If
End Sub
```

**ThisWorkbook**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    vntValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strRange).Value
End Sub
```

### Change

If you are manually changing the values in the cell range `AI2`, you **have to** use the **Worksheet Change** event.

**Standard Module**

```
Option Explicit

Sub macro1()

    Dim rng As Range  ' Target Cell Range
    Dim RV As Long    ' Row Value

    ' In Target Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        ' Calculate the first empty (unused) cell in column A (A1 not included).
        Set rng = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With

    ' In Source Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        ' Write the value of Row Cell to Row Value.
        RV = .Range("AI2").Value
        ' In cell at the intersection of Row Value and column "AH".
        With .Cells(RV, "AH") ' or 33
            ' Copy range from "AB" to "AG" in row defined by Row Value in
            ' Source Worksheet to the range from "A" to "F" in row of Target
            ' Cell Range in Target Worksheet.
            rng.Resize(, 6) = Range(.Offset(0, -6), .Offset(0, -1)).Value
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

**Sheet1**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     Const cCell As String = "AI2"
     If Target = Range(cCell) Then
         If Range(cCell).Value <> "0" Then macro1
     End If
End Sub
```

Like in the **Calculate** version, you might also want to use a public variable (`vntValue`) to prevent triggering `macro1` in case the value in cell range `AI2` hasn't actually changed.